# Dealing with conditional variables in anomaly detection

Tags: machine-learning, anomaly-detection, binary, dummy-variables

I am working on an anomaly detection model and I have a conditional variable, i.e., it is zero or it has an amount like below histogram. Suppose the variable shows the time when a machine is not working during working hours.

[image]

So, when I run the model to detect anomalies, it detects the zeros while they are not considered anomalies. How should I deal with this variable?

Comment: What kind of model as you using?

Comment: Mahalanobis distance using fast MCD and isolation forest

Comment: If the variable is 0, is that always "normal" - without having to consider the interactions with other variables?

Comment: 0 means that the machine is working properly and when it gets a value, it means that the machine is down, and it shows the downtime of the machine.

Comment: And what are some examples of data that is considered an "anomaly" in this usecase?

Comment: when the downtime of the machine is not normal

Comment: Without a definition of "nomal", that is unfortunately a non-answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137622/discussion-between-8simon8-and-jon-nordby).